# npm command not found when working with jest in LWC

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am doing this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/set-up-jest-testing-framework) to get started with testing in LWC.

The first step is to run below command

> sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:setup

But when I run this in terminal, I am getting a below error.

> ERROR running force:lightning:lwc:test:setup:  npm command not found.
> Verify npm is properly installed and try again.

I have verified npm is installed in my system, below is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

as an alternate I downloaded jest library from [git](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest.)

but now not sure how to use this library in my current project so that I can run the next command

> node node_modules/@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/bin/sfdx-lwc-jest

Can someone please suggest on this, I have tried the same thing in different machines and all of them are failing with the same error.

Comment: Do you have nodejs installed. Just type node in CMD or terminal and see what it says.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you try and run npm in some other folder just to check if it is installed globally ? Maybe switch to documents folder and try npm version there.

Comment: Yes, I have tried running in other folders as well, npm -- version works all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

faced same problem  try following , it worked for me.
npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev

Comment: Optionally, with `--global` to apply it to all projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. When executing npm from the VSCode console, VSCode finds it - but when attempting to run sfdx force:lightnin:lwc:test:setup, VSCode reports it cannot find it:

[image: Can find npm but then cannot find npm]

So I ran npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev from windows cmd. That completed with 3149 vulnerabilities reported (none of which could be fixed with npm audit fix - I'm not sure if this is a problem).

Then I could run the unit tests from VSCode.

How does one get around the error in the screenshot though? I have npm on OS path.

[image]